# How should I prepare kola nuts for creating a soft drink?

Tags: drinks, soda

I have recently gotten into making my own soft drinks, and I would like to attempt making a cola.   I found an online spice retailer that sells Kola Nut and bought some, but I have no real idea how to prepare them for use.   I also don't know how much I should use for a liter or two of soda, but I can figure that out via experimentation if I have to.

But what should I do with the kola nuts?   Do they need to be ground before I boil them in a simple syrup, or should the pieces just be dropped in as-is?   How much time does it take to extract the flavor from them?

**Edit:**  I have made my own ginger ale using fresh ginger and my own berry soda using a bag of frozen berries, and I am a homebrewer and have a kegging system and a carbonator cap for soda bottles.   I really just want to know if there are special considerations for how to treat kola nuts.

Answer (score 4):

simple extraction, Grate or coarsely Grind Kola Nuts, Place in alcohol overnight  strain and discard the nuts. and you should have a crude extract. it is likely to have a strong Musky flavour and should be used in trace amounts.

There are more complicated methods of extracting Ie caffeine Extraction.

Have fun.

Answer (score 3):

[Here is a video with instructions](http://www.mahalo.com/how-to-make-cola/). The principle is pretty simple, make an extract from the nuts and mix with water & sugar to taste and carbonate either with CO2 (for a soda) or by fermenting yeast (for a beer or ale).

[Edit] If you treat the kola nuts the same as you would ginger root in order to create your extract you will get where you want to be. A little trial-and-error may be required do discern the preferred concentration.

Comment: Right, but what's the best way to make the kola nut extract?   That video seems to assume you've already got the extract.